# JDBC EZConnect URL: Invalid number format for port number when specifying Protocol

Tags: oracle, jdbc

When specifying a JDBC EZConnect URL to include the Protocol, for example:

jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcps://example1.com:1522/my_service_name
jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcp://example1.com:1522/my_service_name

I am getting the error "Status : Failure - Test Failed: IO Error: Invalid number format for port number"

I am following the example page XXX of the Oracle 19c JDBC Developers Guide (http://ora-srv.wlv.ac.uk/oracle19c_doc/jjdbc/jdbc-developers-guide.pdf)

Does anyone have any input into why this error is occurring ?

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: Side note: I thought "page XXX" was a typo - but it's Roman numerals (my mistake). Here is the full page heading link: [Changes in Oracle Database 19c](http://ora-srv.wlv.ac.uk/oracle19c_doc/jjdbc/jdbc-developers-guide.pdf#_OPENTOPIC_TOC_PROCESSING_d126e16182)

Comment: Are you trying to establish a TCP connection or TCPS connection? 
For TCP: jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521/myorcldbservicename For TCPS, you need more parameters based on whether you are using SSO wallets or JKS. 
Refer to this blog for more details (https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/four-facets-of-database-connectivity-for-java-applications)